# Apply function to one element of a list in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm looking for a concise and functional style way to apply a function to one element of a tuple and return the new tuple, in Python.

For example, for the following input:

```
inp = ("hello", "my", "friend")
```

I would like to be able to get the following output:

```
out = ("hello", "MY", "friend")
```

I came up with two solutions which I'm not satisfied with.

One uses a higher-order function.

```
def apply_at(arr, func, i):
    return arr[0:i] + [func(arr[i])] + arr[i+1:]

apply_at(inp, lambda x: x.upper(), 1)
```

One uses list comprehensions (this one assumes the length of the tuple is known).

```
[(a,b.upper(),c) for a,b,c in [inp]][0]
```

Is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: You could convert your tuple to a (mutable) list, change it's nth element, and convert back to tuple if needed. But if you only need to iterate over the new tuple, why not create a generator that simply yields each element, except for the ith element, where it would yield func(element)? Just an idea though.

Comment: Sure I could just do mylist[idx] = func(mylist[idx]) but I would like a functional-style one-liner solution so that I can use it in a return statement.

Comment: Your first solution is clear, concise, and straightforward. If it bothers you, that suggests to me that it solves the wrong problem. (Incidentally, arr[0:i] can be just arr[:i].)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commented in support of your first snippet, but here are a couple other ways for the record:

```
(lambda (a,b,c): [a,b.upper(),c])(inp)
```

(Won't work in Python 3.x.) And:

```
[inp[0], inp[1].upper(), inp[2]]
```

Comment: Given that what I needed this for is to take the a,b,c returned by a function and return a,b,c with b transformed, I guess your lambda solution is close to the spirit of what I wanted.

It would be nice to have syntactic sugar such a:
    return inp as a, b.upper(), c

The reason I was not completely satisfied with my original apply_at function is that the transformation I want to apply exists only as a method, forcing me to use an anonymous function, unlike the list-comprehension solution.

Your second solution seems to require an intermediate variable for inp if it's not in its own function.

Comment: Would the following work in Python 3.x? (lambda a,b,c: [a,b.upper(),c])(*inp)

Comment: Yes, it should. OK, how I would handle your problem as described: with two statements: a, b, c = inp; return a, b.upper(), c. It's unfortunate that Python isn't expression-oriented like, say, Scheme, but that's how it's meant to be written.

Comment: My preferred alternative is `apply_one = lambda a,f,i: a[:i]+[f(a[i])]+a[i+1:]` where `a`, `f`, `i` are the list, function and index.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a version that works on any iterable and returns a generator:

```
>>> inp = ("hello", "my", "friend")
>>> def apply_nth(fn, n, iterable):
...    return (fn(x) if i==n else x for (i,x) in enumerate(iterable))
... 
>>> tuple(apply_nth(str.upper, 1, inp))
('hello', 'MY', 'friend')
```

You can extend this so that instead of one position you can give it a list of positions:

```
>>> def apply_at(fn, pos_lst, iterable):
...    pos_lst = set(pos_lst)
...    return (fn(x) if i in pos_lst else x for (i,x) in enumerate(iterable))
... 
>>> ''.join(apply_at(str.upper, [2,4,6,8], "abcdefghijklmno"))
'abCdEfGhIjklmno'
```

Comment: Your solution is very elegant and Pythonic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> inp = "hello", "my", "friend"
>>> index = 1
>>> inp[:index] + ( str.upper(inp[index]),) + inp[index + 1:]
('hello', 'MY', 'friend')
```

Seems simple, the only thing you may need to know is that to make a single element tuple, do (elt,)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some' like this?

```
>>>inp = ("hello", "my", "friend")
>>>out =  tuple([i == 1 and x.upper() or x for (x,i) in zip(t,range(len(t)))])

>>> out
('hello', 'MY', 'friend')
```

Note: rather than `(x,i) in zip(t, range(len(t)))` I should have thought of using the enumerate function :  `(i,x) in enumerate(t)`

Making it a bit more general:
Rather than hard-coding the 1, we can place it in a variable.
Also, by using a tuple for that purpose, we can apply the function to elements at multiple indexes.

```
>>>inp = ("hello", "my", "friend")
>>>ix  = (0,2)
>>>out =  tuple([i in ix and x.upper() or x for (i, x) in enumerate(t)])

>>> out
('HELLO', 'my', 'FRIEND')
```

Also, we can "replace" the zip()/enumerate() by map(), in something like

```
out = tuple(map(lambda x,i : i == 1 and x.upper() or x, inp, range(len(inp)) ) )
```

---

Edit: (addressing comment about specifying the function to apply):
Could be something as simple as:

```
>>> f = str.upper  # or whatever function taking a single argument
>>> out = tuple(map(lambda x,i : i == 1 and f(x) or x, inp, range(len(inp)) ) )
```

Since we're talking about applying *any* function, we should mention the small caveat with the `condition and if_true or if_false` construct which is not *exactly* a substitute for the if/else ternary operator found in other languages.  The limitation is that the function cannot return a value which is equivalent to False (None, 0, 0.0, '' for example).  A suggestion to avoid this problem, is, with Python 2.5 and up, to use the true if-else ternary operator, as shown in Dave Kirby's answer (note the `when_true if condition else when_false` syntax of this operator)

Comment: Pretty nice use of logical "and" and "or"! A way to specify the function to apply is also needed. One way is to specify a function as parameter but this forces the user to use an anonymous function (lambda) if the function to apply is a method...

Comment: See my answer for a more pythonic version - python 2.5 onwards has an if-else ternary operator so you do not need to use and&or, and the enumerate function returns a tuple of (index, value) for every element in a sequence so you do not need to muck about with range and len.

Comment: @Dave Kirby: thanks for the hint! I knew about enumerate, but not of the if-else ternary operator in 2.5+.  I'll use this operator more often now, especially that this probably doesn't suffer the caveat I mention (re. False values).  Let me +1 yr answer for teaching me this new trick!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if you want to apply a certain function to every element in the tuple that passes some test, or if you would like it to apply the function to any element present at a certain index of the tuple. So I have coded both algorithms:

This is the algorithm (coded in Python) that I would use to solve this problem in a functional language like scheme:

This function will identify the element identifiable by `id` and apply `func` to it and return a list with that element changed to the output of `func`. It will do this for every element identifiable as `id`:

```
def doSomethingTo(tup, id):
    return tuple(doSomethingToHelper(list(tup), id))

def doSomethingToHelper(L, id):
    if len(L) == 0:
        return L
    elif L[0] == id:
        return [func(L[0])] + doSomethingToHelper(L[1:], id)
    else:
        return [L[0]] + doSomethingToHelper(L[1:], id)
```

This algorithm will find the element at the index of the tuple and apply `func` to it, and stick it back into its original index in the tuple

```
def doSomethingAt(tup, i): 
    return tuple(doSomethingAtHelper(list(tup), i, 0))

def doSomethingAtHelper(L, index, i):
if len(L) == 0: 
        return L
elif i == index: 
        return [func(L[0])] + L[1:]
else: 
        return [L[0]] + doSomethingAtHelper(L[1:], index, i+1)
```

Comment: This would be massively inefficient in Python - If you had a list of length N it would create and destroy N lists, each of length N.  It would also recurse to a depth of N, which may exceed the python stack limit.

Comment: @Dave Kirby: user189637 did ask for a functional approach. Most of what I saw was not functional, hence my solution. As for creating and destroying N many lists, that's what I learned functional programming does. Further, functional programming is meant to be run in a parallel computing environment, therefore it will be inefficient in a serial computing environment.

Answer (score 0):

i also like the answer that Dave Kirby gave. however, as a public service announcement, i'd like to say that this is not a typical use case for tuples -- these are data structures that originated in Python as a means to move data (parameters, arguments) to and from functions... they were not meant for the programmer to use as general array-like data structures in applications -- this is why lists exist. naturally, if you're needing the read-only/immutable feature of tuples, that is a fair argument, but given the OP question, this should've been done with lists instead -- note how there is extra code to either pull the tuple apart and put the resulting one together and/or the need to temporarily convert to a list and back.

Comment: I chose tuple on purpose. As I commented in Darius Bacon's solution, the tuple that I want to transform originates from a return in a function.

Comment: I agree, my original question should have been more detailed. Sorry, this is my first question on stackoverflow.